# Trouble testing copy file function in C

Tags: c, io, path, copy

Okay so this is probably has an easy solution, but after a bit of searching and testing I remain confused.. :(

Here is a snippet of the code that I have written:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int test;
  test = copyTheFile("test.txt", "testdir");
 if(test == 1)
    printf("something went wrong");
 if(test == 0)
    printf("copydone");
 return 0;
}

int copyTheFile(char *sourcePath, char *destinationPath){
    FILE *fin = fopen(sourcePath, "r");
    FILE *fout = fopen(destinationPath, "w");
    if(fin != NULL && fout != NULL){
        char buffer[10000];//change to real size using stat()
        size_t read, write; 

        while((read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fin)) > 0){
            write = fwrite(buffer, 1, read, fout);
            if(write != read)
                return 1;       
        }//end of while
    }// end of if
    else{
        printf("Something wrong getting the file\n");       
        return 0;}
    if(fin != NULL)
        fclose(fin);
    if(fout != NULL)
        fclose(fout);
return 0;
}
```

Some quick notes: I am very new to C, programming, and especially file I/O. I looked up the man pages of fopen, fread, and fwrite. After looking at some example code I came up with this. I was trying to just copy a simple text file, and then place it in the destination folder specified by destinationPath.

The folder I want to place the text file into is called testdir, and the file I want to copy is called test.txt.

The arguments I have attempted to use in the copyFile function are:

- "test.txt" "testdir"
- ".../Desktop/project/test.txt"    ".../Desktop/project/testdir"
- "/Desktop/project/test.txt"     "/Desktop/project/testdir"

I just get the print statement "Something wrong getting the file" with every attempt. I am thinking that it may be because 'testdir' is a folder not a file, but then how would I copy to a folder?

Sorry if this a really basic question, I am just having trouble so any advice would be awesome!

Also, if you wanted to be extra helpful, the "copyTheFile" function is supposed to copy the file regardless of format. So like if its a .jpg or something it should copy it. Let me know if any of you guys see a problem with it.

This is with ISO/POSIX/C89/C99 on Linux.

Comment: If you are on Linux, why are you specifying `C:` in one of your examples? Linux does not have the concept of a C drive.

Comment: Oops, sorry I am coding remotely and I was looking at the wrong path. I will edit it.

Comment: If you are using Linux then the file path separators are the wrong ones. I assume the "test.txt" and "testdir" are in the current directory that you are running the code from. Also you should be using: "test.txt" "testdir/test_copy.txt"

Comment: Hold on... so you are on Windows, but you are logged in remotely to Linux... and you thought you would be able to open a file on your Windows machine in Linux, just by specifying its filename as it appears to Windows? Why would you ever think that would work??

Comment: @RobinGreen

The code I am working on needs to be submitted. I use Filezilla to transfer the files, everything that I work with is on my linux desktop I promise haha

Answer (score 10):

At the start, you'll want to include `stdio.h` to provide `FILE` and the I/O function declarations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Aside from this, your program compiles and works properly for me. Unfortunately you can't copy to a directory without using `stat()` to detect if the destination is a directory, and if so, appending a file name before opening the file.

Some other minor suggestions:

- A buffer with a power of two bytes such as `4096` is probably more efficient due to it lining up with filesystem and disk access patterns
- Conventionally, C functions that return a status code use `0` for success and other values such as `1` for failure, so swapping your return values may be less confusing
- When a standard library function such as `fopen`, `fread` or `fwrite` fails, it is a good idea to use `perror(NULL);` or `perror("error prefix");` to report it, which may look something like:

  ```
  $ ./a.out
  ...
  error prefix: No such file or directory
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the advice I appreciate it! I'll be sure to switch things around.
Also I want to especially say thank you for telling me about perror, I just read the man pages and I think it is going to help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to write a new file in a directory, you should be giving the full path of the file to be written. in your case

`"C:...\Desktop\project\testdir\testfile"`

Comment: It is not necessary to give the full path, and `C:` is not valid for Linux, as already noted.

Comment: @RobinGreen ah I see. thank you for your kind comment. point noted.